Showing that $\operatorname{Spec} k$ is the scheme quotient of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ by an action of $\mathbb{Z}$
This is Exercise 2.3.22 in Liu's book.
The goal is to show that the quotient in the category of schemes of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ under the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $n : T \to T + n$ (on the ring $k[T]$) is $\operatorname{Spec} k$. Here $k$ is a field of characteristic $0$.
We want to show that given a scheme $Z$ and a morphism $f : \mathbb{A}^1_k \to Z$ such that $f = f \circ n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists a unique $\phi : \operatorname{Spec} k \to Z$ such that $f = \phi \circ p$, where $p$ is the morphism from $\mathbb{A}^1_k \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ induced by the inclusion $k \to k[T]$.
If $Z$ is affine, then I'm able to show that this is true by turning the statement into a question about commutative rings, and using the requirement on $f$. But if $Z$ is not affine, I'm stuck trying to show that there exists an affine open subset of $Z$ that contains the entire image of $f$.
My only thought is to use that $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is connected, and that $f$ is continuous, but I feel the solution should leverage the scheme structure of $Z$, although I am not sure how.
Any help is appreciated!

It is not in general true that the image of an affine scheme lands in a single affine chart of the target scheme. Here, however, you could try showing that the image of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is necessarily a single point.

Agreed, although I'm not sure how to show that the image is necessarily a single point. It seems even this has to leverage that the target $Z$ is a scheme, since the topological quotient is not a single point, but I'm not sure how to use that fact...

Can you show that the image is a single point if the image contains at least one closed point of $Z$?

Ah, I think I see the argument, thanks for your help! I'll write up a sketch of the solution as an answer in case any one finds it helpful in the future.

As $\mathbb A^1$ and $\varnothing$ are the only translation-invariant open sets, $f$ is continuous with the indiscrete topology on $\mathbb A^1$. The set-theoretic image must then be indiscrete in the subspace topology of $Z$, but the Zariski topology on a scheme is $T_0$, so the only indiscrete subspaces are singletons.

This seems to work, accepting this answer while debate continues on the others...

As @SergeyGuminov pointed, the image could be any $k$-point of $Z$, not necessarily closed.

I think my hint was misleading, and in fact the sketch of a solution I had in mind turned out to be wrong, so here is an argument. The idea is that instead of looking at the images of closed points, we may look at the image of a generic point and see that it is actually the unique point of the image.
Let $\eta$ be the generic point of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ and consider its image $z=f(\eta)$. Then the whole $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ is mapped to the closure of $z$, and we may replace $Z$ by this closure. So from now on we may assume that $\eta$ is mapped to the generic point $z$ of $Z$.
Consider a point $z'\in \mathrm{im}(f)$. Then the preimage of the closure $\overline{z'}$ is a nonempty closed $G$-invariant subset, which must therefore be all of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$. But we know that $f(\eta)=z$, so $z\in\overline{z'}$. As $z$ is the generic point of $z$, we have $\overline{z'}$ and therefore, $z=z'$.

Can we restrict the codomain of a morphism to a closed set without messing with the sheaf somehow?

@stillconfused There is a universal property for closed subschemes based on only the set-theoretic image of the map which applies here since $\mathbb A^1$ is reduced.

@Ben - that sounds super helpful! Is this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2538503/universal-properties-of-immersion-of-schemes the universal property you're referring to? (See the property for closed immersions in the answer in that post).

@stillconfused there is a better version when the domain runs over only reduced schemes cf. https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0506-216/216ps11.pdf
